# adb + c# отправка файла

Tags: c#, adb

Реализую в c# некоторые команды `adb`. Столкнулся с проблемой, если в пути (в названии) есть пробел или тире.
Вот такой формат использую:

```
(@" adb pull {0} {1}", pathRemote,pathLocal)
```

С одинарными кавычками adb не работает - ругается.
Если двойные, то добавляется экранирование и опять adb не понимает.
Как думаете есть способы?
Можно ли добавить двойные кавычки без экранирования?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Нашел ответ. не знаю насколько корректный, но работает

> string.Format(@" pull ""{0}"" ""{1}", pathRemote, pathLocal);

т.е. последнюю скобку не закрываем

Comment: Бред какой-то, результатом команды будет: `pull "a" "b`, без закрывающей скобки. http://rextester.com/NQYI28255

Comment: сам негодовал, но тем не менее работает

Comment: Это же абсурд. Лучше бы разобрались, что у вас с входящей строкой.

Answer (score 1):

Сама по себе команда `adb pull "путь с пробелами"` прекрасно работает. Создание строки:

```
string path = "путь с пробелами";
string abdCommand = $" adb pull \"{path}\"";
```

Или в вашем случае:

```
string abdCommand = string.Format(@" adb pull ""{0}"" ""{1}""", pathRemote, pathLocal);
```

И там, и там на выходе будет следующая строка:

`adb pull "param 1" "param 2"`

А она является валидной.

Может у вас прблемы со значениями `pathRemote` и `pathLocal`, а не с командой? (`/` в конце не убрали и тд.)

Comment: у меня передается такая команда:
`"adb pull \"/storage/emulated/0/Te st.vcf\" \"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\\""`

В ответ получаю ошибку:
`"adb: error: cannot create 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\"\\Te st.vcf': No such file or directory\r\n"`

Comment: У вас не должно быть экранирования двойных скобок в финальном варианте, а они у вас есть. Пробовали вручную запустить команду `adb pull "/storage/emulated/0/Te st.vcf" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\"`?

Comment: так или иначе они будут. Даже если использовать вариант  `string.Format(@" adb pull ""{0}"" ""{1}""", pathRemote, pathLocal);`
то в при передаче стринга в process будет замена на экранирование (я так понял это правило string'ов).
`adb pull "/storage/emulated/0/Te st.vcf" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\"` пробовал, та же ошибка `"adb: error: cannot create 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\"\\Te st.vcf': No such file or directory\r\n"`

Comment: Второй вариант точно верный, проверил http://rextester.com/UVLPA50356 , значит у вас `path` экранируется еще где то до этого.

Comment: @Art вы же сами говорите, что команда без экранирования не работает... Никакого автоматического экранирования у строк в C# нет (кроме веба), только если их сам автор не поставил раньше. В любом случае, сначала сделайте команду, чтобы она "от руки" работала в `cmd`

Comment: @Максим, 
https://s.mail.ru/DKtA/57bcae4i2
одна из причин почему лучше доверять брекпоинтам, а не дебаг логу))

Comment: @Jagailo, как я уже сказал она отлично работает в cmd с двойными кавычками, но c# добавляет экран в виде слешей, вше добавил скрин. Строки путей туда попадают без экранирования, дальше сами все видите

Comment: @Art - разберитесь, пожалуйста, с тем, как показывается содержимое строк в отладчике при брейкпойнте. Слеш там добавляется именно для визуального отображения. На самом деле его там нет. Поставил минус вашему вопросу. Ибо нефик.

Comment: @Art, в логе не должны скрываться символы. Скорее всего, это это отладчик так строку выводит.